# Closed - Toast message does not show up

Tags: android, android-toast

In this code I want to show up the toast message but it does not show up on clicking. Probably, I have missed something. Could you figure out the problem.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.hacback17.listviewwithinflater;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    String[] days = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
    ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        //Arrayadapter is used to convert the data source into a view.
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list, R.id.textView, days);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView temp = (TextView) view;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, temp.getText() + " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.hacback17.listviewwithinflater.MainActivity">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

simple_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Could you please also write a code snippet for LayoutInflater because I could not understand it properly as yet.
Thanks in advance!

After adding the missed part. The app crashes now. Please have a look at the logcat.

```
Process: com.example.hacback17.listviewwithinflater, PID: 19479
                                                                                            java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
                                                                                                at com.example.hacback17.listviewwithinflater.MainActivity.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:32)
                                                                                                at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
                                                                                                at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1115)
                                                                                                at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2928)
                                                                                                at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3691)
                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: is your onItemClick event working ?

Comment: try - `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, temp.getText() + " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: you missed `listView.setOnItemClickListener(this)`

Comment: @OnkarNene MainActivity.this  and only this both are the same

Comment: @GaneshGudghe I know, but as Toast is created in onItemClick() which is overrided from interface OnItemClickListener. So context might be different.

Comment: You are right. Then I included the missed part. But it crashes now when I click any of these TextView. Please see the Logcat above that I have just added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this way

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    String[] days = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
    ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
         listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        //Arrayadapter is used to convert the data source into a view.
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list, R.id.textView, days);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView temp = (TextView) view;
        Toast.makeText(this, temp.getText() + " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right. Then I included the missed part. But it crashes now when I click any of these TextView. Please see the Logcat above that I have just added.

Comment: Yes, the error is self explanatory but as it reads "LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView", but I don't understand what to do now. (I am beginner in Android so please don't mind if the question looks a bit funny to you.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. It helped me.

Comment: @BABLUKUMAR glad to help happy coding

Comment: Thanks for your kind words.

Answer (score 1):

You just missed this..

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

so,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list, R.id.textView, days);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter)

listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

and check listview by id at there.. It cannot find listview id..

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

 switch(parent.getId()) {
        case R.id.listview:

        TextView temp = (TextView) view;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, temp.getText() + " " + position,     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
            break;

        }

    }
```

I hope, it will help..

Comment: You are right. Then I included the missed part. But it crashes now when I click any of these TextView. Please see the Logcat above that I have just added.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem in onItemClick event.So try this one

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,temp.getText+ " " +position,Toast.LENGH.SHORT).show();
```

Comment: he just missed listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

Answer (score 1):

declare textview like this first then get text from textview

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView temp = (TextView) view;
temp = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        Toast.makeText(this, temp.getText() + " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right. Then I included the missed part. But it crashes now when I click any of these TextView. Please see the Logcat above that I have just added.

Answer (score 0):

Your  setOnItemClickListener  Call back is Missing please add

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

**Hope this will help you**

Comment: You are right. Then I included the missed part. But it crashes now when I click any of these TextView. Please see the Logcat above that I have just added.

Comment: please your java file . Your Are defining wrong id , Means Your giving Text view id to Linear layout in your java file , thats why your application getting crash.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But now I have fixed this problem.Thanks for the trouble.

Comment: Your welocome buddy , happy to help you